# How to get the active control in a function?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I get the active `TextBox` in a function that accept Textbox control as a parameter

```
private void validateTextboxInFocus(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e, KeyEventArgs b, EventArgs c)
{
    string s = ActiveControl.Name;
    labelGago.Text = s;
    String text = labelGago.Text;
    TextBox tb = TextBox.name = text;
    checkTextboxNull(tb);
}
```

Comment: Which are you using WinForms, WPF, or something else?

Comment: The `validateTextboxInFocus` does not accept any parameter of `TextBox`.

Comment: What is `ActiveControl`?

Comment: WPF.  i want to put the focused textbox to the Textbox tb

Comment: after the CLICK event in textbox. i want to put the clicked textbox to the function checktextboxNull() that accepts textbox control

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want to do will be achieved with data binding in WPF. Please refere to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf) for more information. You'll get more by googling "WPF data binding".

If you need to do in this, you should subscribe `KeyDown` or `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox`. Please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.keydown?view=netframework-4.8) and [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-detect-when-text-in-a-textbox-has-changed). You can see code samples in these articles.

---

+1 if this answer is helpful for you!